# Java Multi-threading : Unexpected result

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a Enterprise application. I am facing some issues while running application in multithreaded environment. I am writing a program in which there is a variable whose value is getting updated(incremented) at very fast rate (for example 10000 updates/persecond). A loop runs for certain iterations and the value of the variable is incremented and stored in HashMap. Once the loop terminates and value the variable in HashMap is printed. I am getting unexpected value of the variable.

Here is demo program (Please read comments for better understanding) :

```java
class test implements Runnable {

    static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    static AtomicInteger value_to_be_incremented_stored = new AtomicInteger(0); // variable whose value to be updated
    static AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);  // this runs the loop

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (i.set(0); i.get() < 100000; i.incrementAndGet()) {
            /*
                This loop should run 100000 times and when loop terminates according to me value of variable 
                "value_to_be_incremented_stored" should be 100000 as its value is incremented 
                100000 times the loop also runs 100000 times. 
            */
            System.out.println("Thread > " + Thread.currentThread() + "  " + value_to_be_incremented_stored.incrementAndGet());
            map.put("TC", value_to_be_incremented_stored.intValue());
        }

        System.out.println("Output by Thread  " + Thread.currentThread() + "     " + map.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        test t1 = new test();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(t1);
        thread1.setName("Thread 1");

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(t1);
        thread2.setName("Thread 2");

        Thread thread3 = new Thread(t1);
        thread3.setName("Thread 3");

        Thread thread4 = new Thread(t1);
        thread4.setName("Thread 4");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();

    }
}
```

**Output** (it varies) :

[image: My output]

**Issue** :
I am running loop for 100000 times `(i.get() < 100000)` then how come value of variable `value_to_be_incremented_stored` becomes more than 100000.

Comment: Your variable `i` is probably a mistake.  Read the spec: local variables are thread safe.  Making a loop counter global means it's subject to interference by other threads.  (Instance variables are effectively "global" in a multi-threaded environment.)  Try replacing `i` with just a regular local `int` and test it.

Comment: @markspace I'm betting that making `i` global is intentional.  If he makes it a local `int`, then he should expect `value_to_be_incremented_stored` would get up to 400000, not 100000.

Comment: @markspace  I want overall value to be 100000. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ajb But he sets it to 0 at the start of each loop.  That's got to produce inconsistent results.  *Something* is definitely funky with that loop.

Comment: @markspace yes, that part looks like a mistake; `i.set(0)` should probably be removed.  In fact, I'm sure that's the answer to the problem.

Comment: Well, each time a new thread calls `run()`, you reset the loop counter.  The total number of times that loop runs is indeterminate.  Try just removing the initialization in the for loop: `for ( ; i.get() < 100000; i.incrementAndGet()) {`

Comment: @markspace I removed i.set(0) but still i am getting value more than 100000. I have no clue whats going wrong.

Comment: @ajb I removed i.set(0) but still i am getting value more than 100000.

Comment: Try `while (i.getAndIncrement() < 100000)`.

Comment: Small side note, if I'm not mistaken `value_to_be_incremented_stored` should equal 99,999 once the loop has finished, not 100,000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found three defects.  One there is a race condition in the for loop between the point where you compare the loop counter, and where you increment it.  You should do this in one step to get an atomic operation:

```
for ( ; i.incrementAndGet() < 100000;  ) {
```

The other is there is also a race condition between the increment of your counter, and placing it in the map.  Even though you increment these in series, any thread could be have a different value internally (it's at a different point in the loop) and it could put a previous value in the global map.  You need atomicity here to to make sure the value you increment is the value you place in the loop.

```
synchronized( lock ) { 
    value_to_be_incremented_stored.incrementAndGet();
    map.put("TC", value_to_be_incremented_stored.intValue());
}
```

Finally for some reason the `<` comparison produces a value of 99999 for me.  I had to use `<=` to fix it.

(And as we discussed in the comments, setting `i.set(0)` at the start of each `for` loop doesn't work for fairly obvious reasons.  Four defects, I guess.)

```
class ThreadTestX implements Runnable {

    static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    static AtomicInteger value_to_be_incremented_stored = new AtomicInteger(0); // variable whose value to be updated
    static AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);  // this runs the loop
    static final Object lock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for ( ; i.incrementAndGet() <= 100000;  ) {
            /*
                This loop should run 100000 times and when loop terminates according to me value of variable 
                "value_to_be_incremented_stored" should be 100000 as its value is incremented 
                100000 times the loop also runs 100000 times. 
            */
            synchronized( lock ) {
                value_to_be_incremented_stored.incrementAndGet();
    //            System.out.println("Thread > " + Thread.currentThread() + 
    //                 "  " + value_to_be_incremented_stored.get());
                map.put("TC", value_to_be_incremented_stored.intValue());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Output by Thread  " + Thread.currentThread() 
                + "     " + map.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadTestX t1 = new ThreadTestX();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(t1);
        thread1.setName("Thread 1");

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(t1);
        thread2.setName("Thread 2");

        Thread thread3 = new Thread(t1);
        thread3.setName("Thread 3");

        Thread thread4 = new Thread(t1);
        thread4.setName("Thread 4");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();

    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Output by Thread  Thread[Thread 4,5,main]     {TC=100000}
Output by Thread  Thread[Thread 3,5,main]     {TC=100000}
Output by Thread  Thread[Thread 1,5,main]     {TC=100000}
Output by Thread  Thread[Thread 2,5,main]     {TC=100000}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

---

Afterthoughts:  And in spite of getting marked correct, I'm not sure I was correct.  The problem here is that you are trying to keep three things in sync: the loop counter `i`, the value to be incremented, and the map.  Allowing any of these to be executed outside of a synchronized block may invite them to be in an unexpected state.  I think the following may be safer:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    for ( ;;  ) {
        synchronized( lock ) {
            if( i.incrementAndGet() <= 100000 ) {
                value_to_be_incremented_stored.incrementAndGet();
                map.put("TC", value_to_be_incremented_stored.intValue());
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Output by Thread  " + Thread.currentThread() 
            + "     " + map.toString());
}
```

This removes the need for declaring the variables as `AtomicInteger`, but I don't see how else you ensure that their values don't change (due to some other thread) as that loop executes.

Comment: the synchronize could use the immutable return value of incremantAndGet() as well, so you dont need to synchronize (which makes using atomic types a bit obsolete) `for(;(x=i.incrementAndGet())<100000;)`

Comment: @markspace - Thanks for your answer. this saved my day.

Comment: @eckes I think so too, given the OP's example.  But I think the OPs example may be highly simplified and there might be reasons why the loop invariant cannot be used directly like that in their real problem space.

Answer (score 4):

Your "demo program" suffers from two simultaneous defects.

Defect #1 is the `i.set( 0 )` pointed out by tsolakp.  You say you fixed that but you are still getting a value of more than 100000.  I also tried it and indeed, the final value is still larger than 100000.

I modified the program to be able to create an arbitrary number of threads, and I tried with 3, 10, and 20 threads.  I got a final number of 100003, 100009, and 100019 respectively. See a pattern? So:

Defect #2 is that on the last iteration, when the value of `i` is 99999, the expression `i.get() < 100000` is true for all threads, so all threads proceed to execute once more.  The `i.incrementAndGet()` clause is visually sitting right next to `i.get() < 1000000;` but it does not get executed until the end of the loop.

So, all threads get a chance to increment `i` once more after the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime a new thread enters the run method it will reset your `i` count to zero via the first statement in the for loop by calling `i.set(0)`.

**Update:** Next step after fixing reset issue, is to step through the code and see how the threads will behave. 
Lets say three threads get inside the for loop while the fourth thread increments `i`. What will happen is that `value_to_be_incremented_stored` will increment 3 times and `i` only one time.

Comment: I removed i.set(0) but still i am getting value more than 100000. Sorry to say but this doesnot solve my issue.